# how can i reset the count to 0 in sql when i have a condition that is false?

Tags: sql

i have a sql table which the following data shown in the picture

[image]

I need  to create a query in sql which counts for ticker the number of consecutive days per year in which
the close_value is greater than the open_value, if close_value is less than the open value the counter must be reset to zero and I have to save the counter in that instant

Comment: 1) please tag with appropriate database. 2) do not post pictures of data. Post as text. Otherwise it makes it hard for readers to try to play with the data.

Comment: OK, and? what have you tried? what specific problems did you find?

Comment: In second and 7th row close value is less then open value. Please explain why the count is not set to 0?

Comment: in the photo I show how the table is populated, it is not the final query

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: @MatteoDeSantis Please share your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use the difference of `row_numbers()`:

```
select ticker, min(date), max(date), min(open_value), max(close_value),
       count(*) as num_rows
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ticker order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by ticker, (case when close_value > open_value then 1 else 2 end) order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
where close_value > open_value
group by ticker, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

This returns all such periods.  You haven't specified what the result set should look like, but this should be pretty close.

Comment: I give an example, if in 2013 the consecutive days in which the close_value is greater than the open_value of the AHH ticker is 5 but in 2018 I have 10 days then I have to report 10 and the year 2018